# BackboneJs validation not firing

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I need the console to notify when a song is created without a title
I tried this but the console shows nothing.
A syntax error isn't thrown neither

```
var Song = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:
    {
        title: "default title",
        track: 0
    },
    initialize: function()
    {
        this.on("change:title", function(){
            console.log("title changed");
        }); 

        this.on("error",function(model,error)
        {
            console.log(error);
        });
    },
    validate: function(attribs)
    {   
        if (attribs.title === "default title") 
        {
            return "please set a title";
        }
    }
});

var song1 = new Song;
song1.set({ track: 1});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone 1.1 [slightly changed how validation works](http://backbonejs.org/#upgrading) :

> Model validation is now only enforced by default in save — not in set
>   unless the `{validate:true}` option is passed. Model validation now
>   fires an "invalid" event instead of "error".

Try

```
song1.set({track: 1}, {validate: true});
```

and change your listener to

```
this.on("invalid", function(model, error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/z2p9T/

Comment: thanks you, looks like im reading an outdated book 
"Developing Backbone.js Applications"